# How to discard HTML commands like < chars >?

Tags: java, html

So i'm writting a Java program which I have to add strings to an ArrayList, but I have to discard anything that is inside angle brackets, as well as the angle brackets.

So if the program sees < cake >, it will discard the whole thing and not add it in the ArrayList.

How do i do that? By using replaceAll()? What to put inside the replaceAll() argument?

Comment: Have you tried using regular expressions?

Comment: What you mean regular expressions?

Comment: See [Lesson: Regular Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: You're certainly on the right track with replaceAll() as one solution to your problem.

[Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) Is the Javadoc on that method.

Comment: Why do you call “< chars >” “HTML command”, and do you really mean tags like `<chars>`? If you mean anything from a “<” to the next “>”, do you really mean *anything*?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question, then yes you could use [`replaceAll()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) with a regular expression like,

```
String str = "Hi <test> <abc> 1";
str = str.replaceAll("<.*>", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
Hi  1
```

If you want to remove the excess whitespace there, you could add -

```
String str = "Hi <test> <abc> 1";
str = str.replaceAll("<.*>", "");
str = str.replaceAll("\\s+", " ");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output is

```
Hi 1
```

Comment: Good example of basic code to do this. If you're concerned about actual secure sanitizing of HTML, have a look here:  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_Filter_Evasion_Cheat_Sheet

Comment: Ok, when i used that like this:  
String temp = scan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("<.*>","");


I got <, chars, > as my output. What's going on?

Comment: Are you outputting `temp`? Are you sure?

Comment: No, I'm outputting the arraylist, which is made of temps like this:      ArrayList.add(temp);